# Lifetime of async closure return type

Tags: rust, async-await, lifetime

Consider the following code:

```rust
async fn f(x: &i32) -> i32 {
    todo!()
}

fn g<F, Fut>(f: F)
where
    F: Send + Sync + 'static,
    for<'a> F: Fn(&'a i32) -> Fut,
    Fut: Future<Output = i32> + Send + Sync,
{
    todo!()
}

fn main() {
    g(f);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0353cb3ceecb7a6bab9d34ee0f1ead54)

The compiler complains with

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:17:5
   |
17 |     g(f);
   |     ^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected associated type `<for<'_> fn(&i32) -> impl Future {f} as FnOnce<(&i32,)>>::Output`
              found associated type `<for<'_> fn(&i32) -> impl Future {f} as FnOnce<(&'a i32,)>>::Output`
   = note: the required lifetime does not necessarily outlive the empty lifetime
note: the lifetime requirement is introduced here
  --> src/main.rs:10:31
   |
10 |     for<'a> F: Fn(&'a i32) -> Fut,
   |                               ^^^
```

I think the issue is that the lifetime of the return value in the async function is tied to the lifetime of `x`, but I'm not sure how to express this in the `where` clause for `g`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are looking for this:

```
use core::future::Future;

async fn f(x: &i32) -> i32 {
    todo!()
}

fn g<'a, F, Fut>(f: F)
where
    F: Send + Sync + 'static,
    F: Fn(&'a i32) -> Fut,
    Fut: Future<Output = i32> + Send + Sync,
{
    todo!()
}

fn main() {
    g(f);
}
```

Bind the lifetime of x to that of g (don't know for sure if this is what you want .. i don't know of a way to do this in the where clause)

Comment: I think that works for my example. Do you know if it's possible make g a struct instead of a function, e.g. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bf0c474f83f9cec0d1348ed17b9dccce. That unfortunately doesn't seem to compile.

Comment: @hasali19 maybe you could ask a new question for that.

Comment: Sure, I'll mark this as the answer for this one then

Comment: Yeah, a different question is better since things are a little different with structs

Comment: The question for how to do this using a struct can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67992216/lifetimes-when-wrapping-async-function-in-struct).