# Lifetime bound in Async function which is also an argument

Tags: asynchronous, rust, arguments, lifetime

I'm trying to pass an async function as an argument. The async fucntion accepts a reference as it's arguemnt.

```rust
use std::future::Future;

async fn f(x: &i32) -> i32 {
    todo!()
}

async fn g<F, Fut>(f: F)
where
    F: Send + Sync + 'static + for<'a> Fn(&'a i32) -> Fut,
    Fut: Future<Output = i32> + Send + Sync,
{
//    let x = 3;
//    f(&x).await;
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    g(f).await;
}
```

But I've got compile error.

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:18:5
   |
18 |     g(f).await;
   |     ^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected associated type `<for<'_> fn(&i32) -> impl Future<Output = i32> {f} as FnOnce<(&i32,)>>::Output`
              found associated type `<for<'_> fn(&i32) -> impl Future<Output = i32> {f} as FnOnce<(&'a i32,)>>::Output`
   = note: the required lifetime does not necessarily outlive the empty lifetime
note: the lifetime requirement is introduced here
  --> src/main.rs:9:55
   |
9  |     F: Send + Sync + 'static + for<'a> Fn(&'a i32) -> Fut,
   |                                                       ^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `test-async-tokio` due to previous error
```

Why lifetime is introduced by `Fut` here?
How to specify the lifetime bound for this code?

Best regards!

Comment: If you change to a proper lifetime param like `g<'a, ...>` instead of `for<'a>` in the trait bound, the error is slightly clearer: `x` borrowed with lifetime `'a` but dropped at end of scope. Still trying to figure out why that's an issue though, since you awaited it...

Comment: I've changed to lifetime annotation as you said. But `g` used a local variable `x`. And reference to `x` cannot be bounded to 'a.   `F: Send + Sync + 'static + Fn(&'a i32) -> Fut,`

Comment: [This Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67993568/1926020) works well. I can move the async function to a struct wrapper. But it is a little complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From further testing, it appears that my original suggestion of changing the `'a` lifetime param from a `for<'a>` clause on the trait bound to a proper generic parameter causes the the compiler to think that the lifetime exists within the returned future, which prevents locals from being used. This seems to be the case even if I explicitly apply the `'a` lifetime bound to `Fut` and await the result.

I'm not entirely certain why the trait bounds you have established are not working, but I believe it is somehow due to async functions returning `impl Future` rather than a known concrete type. I was running into this issue in a few deviations from your original code. [This source](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/lifetimes-with-async-function-parameters/51338/2) seems to be a solution to your problem, and I've included below a modified example for your specific use case. *Note: I renamed the `f` param to `y` to emphasize that it is not calling the `f` function directly.*

This solution adds a new trait (with blanket impl) that can be used as a trait bound for `F` directly, with a `for<'a>` clause needed if the input/output is a reference. I could be mistaken, but it seems like this works because the unknown concrete future type is wrapped up into the new trait as an associated type, so `g` and its trait bounds don't need to worry about it directly.

```rs
use std::future::Future;

trait AsyncFn<T>: Fn(T) -> <Self as AsyncFn<T>>::Fut {
    type Fut: Future<Output = <Self as AsyncFn<T>>::Output>;
    type Output;
}
impl<T, F, Fut> AsyncFn<T> for F where F: Fn(T) -> Fut, Fut: Future {
    type Fut = Fut;
    type Output = Fut::Output;
}

async fn f(_: &i32) -> i32 {
    todo!()
}

async fn g<F>(y: F) where F: for<'a> AsyncFn<&'a i32, Output = i32> {
    let x = 3;
    let res = y(&x).await;
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    g(f).await;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer sincerely. This helper `AsyncFn` is amazing. Your explanation seems to be right, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67992216/lifetimes-when-wrapping-async-function-in-struct/67993568#67993568) But I'm still confused about the lifetime. There's still a lot for me to learn.

Comment: @readytogo To be honest, I'm still confused on the exact cause of the error, but this fixes it nicely. Lifetimes aren't usually this bad, but async makes it messy since they're really returning state machines under the hood, and locals are part of that state.

Comment: I've learned from someone else.

As methioned in [rust rfc document](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2394-async_await.html),

`async fn f(x: &i32) -> i32 {...}`
 has an equivalent type signature to 
`fn f<'a>(arg: &'a str) -> impl Future<Output = i32> + 'a { ... }`.

While the function signature in `g`
`F: Send + Sync + 'static + for<'a> Fn(&'a i32) -> Fut,`.
`Fut` is not bounded to lifetime `'a`.

So `F` and `f` are not the same.

Comment: Works like a charm. Here a variant w/ 3 params
`trait AsyncFn<T, U, V>: Fn(T, U, V) -> <Self as AsyncFn<T, U, V>>::Fut {
    type Fut: Future<Output = <Self as AsyncFn<T, U, V>>::Output>;
    type Output;
}

impl<T, U, V, F, Fut> AsyncFn<T, U, V> for F
where
    F: Fn(T, U, V) -> Fut,
    Fut: Future,
{
    type Fut = Fut;
    type Output = Fut::Output;
}`